# Name that Song (Part 1?)

Tags: rebus, knowledge

Here are some lines from songs. See if you can name them. You should include the artist name in your answer, even though the artist names do not appear as part of the rebus.

1.

```
                      ↓
bozo,pennywise|       iu       |hamill,romero
```

2.

$u(me) = em \approx record$

3.

```
u+99, i+(i     i), u+GGG, i+#|
```

**Hint**:

> These are listed in chronological order by release date.

**Edit**:

I have updated #1 to make it easier.
I have updated #2 just for fun.
I have updated #3 to be a closer representation of the lyrics of the song.

Comment: On a semi related note: 99 problems, the official song of puzzling?

Comment: Foes that wanna make sure my question's closed? :(

Comment: The third one reminds me of Problem by Ariana Grande…  I have no idea why.

Comment: #3: blank space? Just an idea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Partial answer.

**3**

> Weezer's "Hash Pipe".

u+99

> you've got your problems (99 of them, here. lol)

i+(i        i)

> I've got my eyes wide

u+GGG

> You've got your big G's

i+#|

> I've got my hash pipe

Comment: This one took a second, because although "99 problems" was wrong, it's a good clue.

Comment: I upvoted these three answers, but marked this one with the check as it was the hardest of the three to solve (as expected). See [#1](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18124/10399) and [#2](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18118/10399).

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure the line is "I've got my eyes wide", but you got the gist of it anyway.

Comment: Hmm. It's different to different sources, but "I've got my eyes wide" makes a hell of a lot more sense given the subject of the song.

Answer (score 7):

*Partial answer...*

2.

> Right Round by Dead or Alive
>  The lyric is, 'You Spin Me Right Round'

Comment: Now it's "like a record". Baby.

Answer (score 7):

#1

> Stuck in the Middle With You by Stealers Wheel

Lyrics:

> `Clowns to the left of me, Jokers to the right, 
> Here I am, stuck in the middle with you.`

Reason:

> `Bozo and Pennywise are clowns (on the left) , Hamill and Romero (on the right) are actors who played The Joker
> And I (me) is in the middle stuck to U (you)`

Comment: You've got the song right, but there are more lyrics in the first rebus.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Oups. Edited.

Comment: Lol that simultaneous edit :)